# What is causing this strange TypeError in my random forest code?

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, tensorflow, random-forest

I have some pretty simple code training a random forest on a data from a csv. The code, minus imports and constants can be found below:

```
def build_estimator(model_dir):
  """Build an estimator."""
  params = tensor_forest.ForestHParams(
      num_classes=2, num_features=5,
      num_trees=FLAGS.num_trees, max_nodes=FLAGS.max_nodes)
  graph_builder_class = tensor_forest.RandomForestGraphs
  if FLAGS.use_training_loss:
    graph_builder_class = tensor_forest.TrainingLossForest
  # Use the SKCompat wrapper, which gives us a convenient way to split
  # in-memory data like MNIST into batches.
  return estimator.SKCompat(random_forest.TensorForestEstimator(
      params, graph_builder_class=graph_builder_class,
      model_dir=model_dir))


model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp() if not FLAGS.model_dir else FLAGS.model_dir
est = build_estimator(model_dir)

COLUMNS = [ "a", "b", "c",
           "d", "e", "f"]
postData = pd.read_csv("PostData2Cut.csv", names=COLUMNS, skipinitialspace=True, dtype=np.float32)

est.fit(x=postData[["a", "b", "c",
           "d", "e"]], y=postData[["f"]],
          batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size)
```

When I get to the est.fit line though it crashes saying the following:

```
TypeError: Input 'input_data' of 'CountExtremelyRandomStats' Op has type float64 that does not match expected type of float32.
```

Apparently this is occuring in some tensorflow file called op_def_library.py on the following line of code:

```
apply_op
    (prefix, dtypes.as_dtype(input_arg.type).name))
```

Not really sure what could be causing this. I seem to be saying the values read from the csv should be of type float32. Getting really frustrated by this. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: what happens if you say dtype=np.float64 in your pd.read_csv call?

Comment: it crashes, telling me it can't convert the categorical string values into floats :/

Comment: Are you able to use tf.cast() to put everything in float32?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and tf.cast() solved the problem.

```
training_set = tf.cast(training_set, tf.float32)
```

See this answer:
[TypeError when training Tensorflow Random Forest using TensorForestEstimator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45085545/typeerror-when-training-tensorflow-random-forest-using-tensorforestestimator)