# TypeError when training Tensorflow Random Forest using TensorForestEstimator

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, random-forest

I get a TypeError when attempting to train an Tensorflow Random Forest using TensorForestEstimator.

```
TypeError: Input 'input_data' of 'CountExtremelyRandomStats' Op has type float64 that does not match expected type of float32.
```

I've tried using Python 2.7 and Python 3, and I've tried using tf.cast() to put everything in float32 but it doesn't help. I have checked the data type on execution and it's float32. The problem doesn't seem to be the data I provide (csv of all floats), so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Any suggestions of things I can try would be much appreciated.

Code:

```
# Build an estimator.
def build_estimator(model_dir):
  params = tensor_forest.ForestHParams(
      num_classes=2, num_features=760,
      num_trees=FLAGS.num_trees, max_nodes=FLAGS.max_nodes)
  graph_builder_class = tensor_forest.RandomForestGraphs
  if FLAGS.use_training_loss:
    graph_builder_class = tensor_forest.TrainingLossForest
  # Use the SKCompat wrapper, which gives us a convenient way to split in-memory data into batches.
  return estimator.SKCompat(random_forest.TensorForestEstimator(params, graph_builder_class=graph_builder_class, model_dir=model_dir))


# Train and evaluate the model.
def train_and_eval():

  # load datasets
  training_set = pd.read_csv('/Users/carl/Dropbox/Docs/Python/randomforest_balanced_train.csv', dtype=np.float32, header=None)
  test_set = pd.read_csv('/Users/carl/Dropbox/Docs/Python/randomforest_balanced_test.csv', dtype=np.float32, header=None)

  print('###########')
  print(training_set.loc[:,1].dtype)  # this prints float32

  # load labels
  training_labels = pd.read_csv('/Users/carl/Dropbox/Docs/Python/randomforest_balanced_train_class.csv', dtype=np.int32, names=LABEL, header=None)
  test_labels = pd.read_csv('/Users/carl/Dropbox/Docs/Python/randomforest_balanced_test_class.csv', dtype=np.int32, names=LABEL, header=None)

  # define the path where the model will be stored - default is current directory
  model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp() if not FLAGS.model_dir else FLAGS.model_dir
  print('model directory = %s' % model_dir)

  # build the random forest estimator
  est = build_estimator(model_dir)

  tf.cast(training_set, tf.float32) #error occurs with/without casts
  tf.cast(test_set, tf.float32)
  # train the forest to fit the training data
  est.fit(x=training_set, y=training_labels)  #this line throws the error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using tf.cast in incorrect manner

```
tf.cast(training_set, tf.float32) #error occurs with/without casts
```

should be

```
training_set = tf.cast(training_set, tf.float32)
```

tf.cast is **not** in-place method, it is a tensor flow op, as any other operation, and needs to be assigned and run.

Comment: Hi, I have had a similar problem, but this solution doesn't work for me? I am not sure if my issue is the same as this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392269/tensorflow-skcompat-converting-float32-values-in-pandas-dataframe-to-tf-float64